# Store and Retrieve Multiple Avatar Image Sizes

Tags: database

I am building a forum type site whereby the users will have an avatar. The main page will have a small version whereas the single page will have a large version of the avatar.

So for sake of bandwidth, I will have different sizes:

```
example.png
example_thumb.png
```

What is the preferred storage and retrieval method for the different sizes?

Here's what I have come up with so far:

```
User Table    UserId  |  AvatarName  |  AvatarExt
              1       |  example     |  .png
```

This way I can get the base and thumb version with the same query as long as I know that there is a '_thumb' version

Or should I create a meta table like so:

```
UserMeta      UserId  |  Avatar             |  AvatarType
              1       |  example.png        |  original
              1       |  example_thumb.png  |  thumbnail
```

I would love some advice

Comment: I would shy away from calling it UserMeta - that doesn't really capture the relationship. The relationship is really a one to many from users to avatars. So, you should have a table for users, and a table for avatars, with 0 or more records in the avatars table for every user. You would typically have 2 records for each user based on your current needs, but say you decide later to allow users to have multiple avatars - you don't really need to change this structure to accomodate that.

Comment: I used 'UserMeta' for the example. I know exactly what you mean by making it a better name. You've been a HUGE help, thanks a bunch man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Users:

```
id
username
...
```

Avatars

```
id
user_id
avatar_type(original, thumbnail)
file_name
```

Then you can do:

```
select * from avatars where user_id = $user_id and avatar_type='thumbnail'
```

This allows you to, say, allow users later on to have multiple avatars without modifying your tables.

Comment: the sql statement just made it all seem so simple! thats awesome, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Either one will work, though I would go with the meta table for ease of use, in particular if the extension is not expected to change.

I don't see any benefit in storing the filename and extension in separate columns.