# Best practice for storing images in a database?

Tags: database, image, thumbnails

I'm creating a web application that needs to store various images. A good example would be an event site:
There are events that have Flyers + Photos (belonging to an event) and Locations that have also photos (belonging to a location).
But I have some troubles creating an ideal solution for all this, because I want to be very flexible. So Photos should be available in multiple resolutions, Flyers could have a back side and thumbnails as well.

Currently I just store the path to the original image in the database and "calculate" the other paths with adding "_small" or "_800x600" to the file name. Although with this approach I have to clean up all the thumbnails when changing a flyer, because I don't keep track of the thumbnails.

So what is the best practice for this? Should I store the paths for the thumbnails too? Are there any famous examples on how to do this? It seems like a rather common problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a search on SO? There are many answers to many similar questions.

Comment: Of course I did. But the discussions were all about "store in files vs. store in database" which is not the issue here.

Comment: Check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068168/store-multiple-sizes-of-one-image-filesystem-or-database-approach

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237272/store-and-retrieve-multiple-avatar-image-sizes

Comment: Alternate idea, use SLIR to resize images on the fly. Github repo here: https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR